# Problems using Netlify to host Gatsby built site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

Im getting this error

./node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/gatsby-browser-entry.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (26:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

```
    |
    |  return (
    |    <React.Fragment>
    |      {finalData && render(finalData)}
    |      {!finalData && <div>Loading (StaticQuery)</div>}
```

gatsby-browswer-entry.js only has this inside of it:
 `import './src/styles/tailwind.css'`

None of my .js files are failing to import the 'Link' component

Comment: Does it build locally?

Comment: I don't understand, what You mean by "None of my .js files are failing to import the 'Link' component". What happens, if You remove the import, than import something else? If the error disappears, check the imported CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, depending on Gatsby's version and its dependencies, you need to import the  component from `gatsby-link` rather than `gatsby`, so:

```
// import { Link } from "gatsby" // error 
import Link from "gatsby-link" // not error
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and was only exposed when running tests in cypress. I had used gatsby's navigate function in a non-jsx javascript helper file. I think the error is indicative of a bundling / webpack issue and you have to look at the stack trace to see the actual culprit file.